# Enable VideoJS to play .mov

Tags: ffmpeg, wordpress, video.js, mov, video-conversion

I have set up a wordpress theme called Video Board, the site I am building allows users to upload their videos for comments. Uploading a video from a mobile device is critical, the theme supports mp4 which covers android users, however it does not support .mov. Has anyone come across a way to play .mov in videojs?

The server has ffmpeg installed, however the last plugin I tried needed its own upload page which worked however videos were not captured in the themes latest uploads/popular posts etc.

I know a conversion would be the proper way to do it, but at this point I would even be happy working out a way that when users upload videos through the theme upload page, it doesn't actually convert but just changes the file extension(renames) it to .mp4, as that is all I have been doing to fill out some content.

I am open to all suggestions,

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

There are [tech plugins](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins#playback-techs-support-media-from-different-sources) for video.js, but these will require browser plugins. You're far better off converting the mov files after upload to standard formats, e.g. h264/acc MP4